# Trying to manually recreate a simple generate/scaffolding script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to understand Rails from the ground up. I want to learn how to manually create basic show-all/show-single/CRUD functionality in the framework.

I currently am working on the display-all functionality, but am stopped by an error when I try to request all items in the Products db

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. *script/generate controller Products*
2. *script/generate model Products*
3. *rake db:migrate*
4. modified products_controller.rb to add: *def index() { @products = Product.all}*
5. (error: uninitialized constant ProductsController::Product)
6. ideally, dump all orders in the view

What's the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate your model you should be using either the lower case plural version or the Camel case singular.

so `script/generate model Product` or `script/generate model product`

In summary a model Product lives in app/models/product.rb and uses a database table products. When you have multi-word model names such as OrderItem this lives in app/models/order_item and uses a database table called order_items

Your original question also does not show any columns added when the model generator was run, I assume you have left those out for conciseness. Otherwise you may have a table with very few columns.

Comment: Right. Your model should be singular, your controller for that model should be plural.